# Laravel 5 redirect www issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect

Whenever i'm going to a url on my site it ends up going to the www. version which is fine. If i go to www.mydomain.com/services all loads perfectly. However.

when i go to mydomain.com/services or any other variation it always redirects me back to www.mydomain.com/index.php

I've had a look at the .htaccess and it all looks fine unless I have missed something? Could it be a laravel configuration issue?

Heres my htaccess below.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

## www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: check your routes.php and sessions

Comment: You need to move that last rule block up just after `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: I had a little play around with moving that last block up and i don't use an sessions currently. can seem to get it working.

I do currently have only 4-5 static pages for the moment and nothing complex

Comment: meant to say can't seem to*

Comment: Perhaps clear your cache? Not sure that'll help... Or you could replace your block with [this one](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-www-in-a-generic-way).

Comment: seems it was the trailing slash block causing all the issues. works fine now.